# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 laravel5

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

i created a site with laravel framework and I used laravel server via composer (url localhost:8000) and every thinks were good
i moved the site under my xampp sever under htdocs folder and with a simple htaccess redirection every thinks were good
and when i moved the site to the dev server
Exemple : http://www.devserver.com/myapplication
I got this error:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821
```

The app url is

'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://www.devserver.com/myapplication /'),

An the htacces file is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

my "route.php" file content is :

```
Route::get('/', 'homecontroller@home');
//encode
Route::get('/encode', 'Controller@encode');
//decode
Route::get('/decode', 'Controller@decode');
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not edit original `.htaccess` file and do not add any new ones. You should add virtual host in xampp which sets `public` directory as root, something like:

```
<VirtualHost yourapp.app:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/yourapp/public"
    ServerName yourapp.app
    ServerAlias yourapp.app

    <Directory "C:/yourapp/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You can even use exactly this virtual host if you'll add this to `hosts` file and restart Windows:

```
127.0.0.1   yourapp.app
```

And then you can just use `yourapp.app` in your browser instead of `localhost:8000`.

BTW, after doing any changes restart Apache.